# Clarification needed on sign/constellation Makara (Capricorn)

Tags: universe

Yesterday I was browsing some links and learnt that astrologically, 'Vishnu Nabhi' or the 'Navel of Sri Vishnu' is said to be aligned at the constellation of Gemini (Mithuna). But the text was too lengthy and said certain things about sign Makara too, that is, that sign Makara is the galactic anti-center and that the axis of the evolution of the galaxy lies along the Cancer-Capricorn sphere. Is this correct? What is the right term to phrase the sign Capricorn - as 'Galactic anti-center'?

Comment: Is the user account [JRD](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/13021/jrd) yours? If yes, merge your accounts.  See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), Use only one account.

Comment: Already I had scored 58 points in this very same account and you deleted my account and I lost all my points and restarted it. Now I did not start any new account. Once again same question. I have no clue why there is another jrd account, because I have not created it.

Comment: Which account are you talking about the one I linked or the one you asked this question? That account is not yours. This is what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes, this account that says jrd with 53 reputation points and 4 bronze medals with +52 under 'reputation changes' is only mine. 1 month ago, I initially had 58 points under this account. Then I accidentally created another account which was deleted. I somehow lost all points. Then I logged back in as jrd and now started from scratch and scored 53 points and 4 bronze medals. I do not want to lose them. But I want to have the other account deleted. Thanks.

Comment: @jrd Which account you created and lost??. I can merge your accounts.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, I'm confused... all I know of is this account called 'jrd' wherein today (Jan 28th) I right now have 123 points and 5 bronze medals. I am not sure how to find out about my other accounts...

Comment: @jrd This is your other account https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/13021/jrd